# How to assign UItextfield property to another UItextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to transfer a `UITextField` properties to another `UITextField`. How can I do so?

Here's my complete scenario:

I have created a custom cell in which I have a UITextField.

Now when I'm using this UITextField in my UITableView i want to assign already existing

UITextField's property to this cell's UITextField. I tried

```
cell.myCustomTextField = myAlreadyCreatedTextField;
```

Also tried to transfer individual properties like

```
cell.myCustomTextField.borderStyle = myAlreadyCreatedTextField.borderStyle;
```

but this also didn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need multiple UITextFields with the same properties you can make an initializer like this.

```
myField = [self fieldWithLabel:@"Placeholder" withTextField:myField withFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,260,45) withKeyboard:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

//

```
-(UITextField *)fieldWithLabel:(NSString *)name withTextField:(UITextField *)field
                     withFrame:(CGRect)frame withKeyboard:(UIKeyboardType)keyboard
{
    CGRect fieldFrame = frame;
    field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldFrame];
    field.placeholder = name;
    field.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    field.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    field.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    field.enabled = YES;
    field.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically= NO;
    field.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    field.delegate = self;
    field.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    field.keyboardType = keyboard;

    return field;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**IN SHORT :** It is not possible to assign a property of one control to another control.
Because Apple/iOS does not provide this type of feature.

But you can get **text** of one `UITextField` to another `UITextField`, by

```
textField1.text = textField2.text;
```

Comment: Yes text can be transfered that is fine but what about other properties such as border style and all..?

Comment: "Apple/iOS does not provide this type of feature"
correct..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Controls (like NSTextField) each have an associated cell which
contains the display attributes of the control. NSCell and its
subclasses implement copying, so you can copy the cell instead of the
view (which does not support NSCopying).

Alternatively, NSViews support NSCoding, so generally speaking if you
have a view or subclass that you need to replicate, one way to do it
is to archive it and then unarchive it for however many "copies" you
might need.

From [Source](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/175001-how-can-copy-duplicate-an-existing-nstextfield.html).